# get ip addresses of azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set as output

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Can I somehow get the internal IP addresses of the created VMs of an [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set) with a fixed amount of instances as output variable?

I went through the documentation but didn't find any export related to the virtual machines created.

Comment: You are asking about `ip_configuration` block?

Comment: @MarkoE no, I'd like to get the information I would normally get in the "Instances" section of the Azure Portal. So if I set `instances` to `3`, I'd like to have the 3 private IP addresses of the provisioned instances as output.

Answer (score -1):

*I tried to create the Internal IP address of the created vm in my environment and got the below results*

> The below script  I have taken from this terraform [URL](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set) and modified as per the requirement

```
locals {
  first_public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC+wWK73dCr+jgQOAxNsHAnNNNMEMWOHYEccp6wJm2gotpr9katuF/ZAdou5AaW1C61slRkHRkpRRX9FA9CYBiitZgvCCz+3nWNN7l/Up54Zps/pHWGZLHNJZRYyAB6j5yVLMVHIHriY49d/GZTZVNB8GoJv9Gakwc/fuEZYYl4YDFiGMBP///TzlI4jhiJzjKnEvqPFki5p2ZRJqcbCiF4pJrxUQR/RXqVFQdbRLZgYfJ8xGB878RENq3yQ39d8dVOkq4edbkzwcUmwwwkYVPIoDGsYLaRHnG+To7FvMeyO7xDVQkMKzopTQV8AuKpyvpqu0a9pWOMaiCyDytO7GGN you@me.com"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resourcesabc"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-networkabc"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "example" {
  name                = "vmssabc"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 3
  admin_username      = "adminuser"

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = local.first_public_key
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  network_interface {
    name    = "example"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name      = "internal"
      primary   = true
      subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    }
  }
}
```

> Run the following script

```
terraform init
```

[image]

```
terraform plan
```

[image]

```
terraform apply
```

[image]

*When I open and check the virtual machine scale set i am able to see the 3 instances created*

[image]

*I opened the Vm instance, I am able to  see the terraform created Private IP address*

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the whole point is that I want the IP addresses as *output variables* of Terraform in order to apply automation

Comment: @muffel resource "azurerm_instance" "my-instance" {
      count         = "${var.instance_count}"
      instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
      tags = {
        Name  = "${element(var.instance_tags, count.index)}"
      }
    }
    output "ip" {
      value = "${azurerm_instance.my-instance.*.public_ip}"
    }
Like this are you trying to get? then Refer this [URL](https://bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Terraform/Terraform-output-variables.php)